# Unboxing Berkley Jensen Winter Ice Melt

Tags: ice

I bought Berkley Jensen Winter Ice Melt from BJs. But I do not know how to open its cap. I searched youtube and google and still did not get it. Here is the weblink of the product:
[LINK](https://www.bjs.com/product/berkley-jensen-winter-heat-ice-melt-50-lbs/3000000000000155589)

Anybody can help?

Comment: Looks like the top of the bucket unscrews. Try turning the top counter-clockwise.

Comment: Following the link, there is a Q&A box further down with exactly the same question. But no answer. Would be cool, if it gets answered there as well

Comment: The only other time I have seen a bucket lid that "thick" was because it had threads on it and screwed off.  If you could supply more pictures that would help.  I'm seeing two types of buckets online, and one of the lids looks more like a paint bucket with a strip that tears off then the lid prys off.

Comment: Thanks all your guys tips. I could turn the top but it is just turning without help. There is a small thread at one side of cover, which supposed to be peeled off. But when I tried to tear it off, it accidentally broke apart. Finally I used my hammer and knocked off the cover after several brutal smash. I asked a staff when I later get to BJs, and he said that the thread must be carefully peeled off first, and I did nothing wrong. Anyway, I don't understand why it is designed in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to score the top with a box cutter and then smash it with a hammer!

[image]

Comment: Did you intend to post the same picture twice? If not, feel free to [edit] your post and include the proper second picture.

Comment: Neat hammer, It turned the lid White. What happened between cutting it open and putting a white lid on it?

Answer (score 1):

It’s dumb that the box has no instructions.

But here’s how to do it.

1. Look for a pull tab around the rim. You need to pull the tab so that the plastic pulls all the way off around the lid. I had to use a screwdriver as leverage to get the pull tab out and get started pulling.
2. When you are done, you will see 3 or 4 ridges the hang down over the rim which look like you can grab and pull them up. You can’t.
3. You have to use those to turn the lid counter clockwise about 2-3 inches. It’s not easy to turn because you have to hold this big can tight while doing it.
4. Finally, grab a hammer and use the claw pull up the lid. Stick the claw under those ridges that hang down, and use leverage to pop each of them up and open the lid.
5. For closing it, I just pushed the lid down hard and didn’t bother twisting it back.